# 1432 - Can't create federated table. The data source connection string %s is not in the correct format

Tags: mysql

I am having issue in federating data from remote server into my local machine.
My Remote table is MyISAM , when i tried to execute

```
CREATE TABLE `wtc_test (
    `wtc_companyworkday_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=FEDERATED  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://pentah:0p@l@192.1**.*.*:3306/replica/wtc_test';
```

I got Following error :-

> `[Err] 1432 - Can't create federated table. The data source connection string 'mysql://pentah:0p@l@192.1*.*:3306/replica/wtc_test' is not in the correct format`

The reason i see is, my password contains '@' character, can some one help me .

Comment: Tried by changing format "mysql://'pentah':'0p@l'@'192.1*.*:3306'/replica/wtc_test , but same error

Comment: Had the same problem I wasn't following the docs after all. I neglected to add the remote database and table into the connection string. The proper connection string would have been FOR me :mysql://user:password@host.name:3306/remote_db/table

Comment: I followed the same as you have specified ,:mysql://pentah:0p@l@192.1**.*.*:3306/replica/wtc_test , same error .How does password handle special symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard in MySQL usernames/hosts is `%`, not `*`. Apart from that, what you specify there is the destination, not the source like when you create a user or grant privileges. So you better specify a hostname or the static IP of your MySQL database server.

And have a try with `"` around your password, as single quotes would terminate the connection string.

```
CONNECTION='mysql://pentah:"0p@l"@yourHost:3306/replica/wtc_test';
```

But if I were you, I would simply change the password. A password is not safe by using the most exotic symbols, it's the length that matters. Have a look at [this](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: Please guide me if i am wrong ,i am  federating data from remote server into my local machine , so in my local i need to mention Remote connection properties , i did used Remotehostname and Quoted my password  "0p@l" , still same error [Err] 1432 - Can't create federated table. The data source connection string 'mysql://pentah:"0p@l"@RemoteHost:3306/replica/wtc_test' is not in the correct format

Comment: Try changing the password and remove those " again, please.

Comment: With the change of password did the trick ,thanks a ton for ur support , so how can i handle special symbols in password

Comment: I would have to try myself, maybe you can escape them with `...pentah:0p\@l@remotehost...`.

Comment: If you find some time,can you please reply to this , do Federated engine copies a table from Remote database to local database (or) Federated engine creates virtual table in local database from remote database .

Comment: No, it's a virtual table, like a view, just the results of selects are sent over network.

Comment: i did that ;-) , so can u suggest me any way , so that data needs to be updated in local server (This means physical storage in both the places local and remote )

Comment: On the answer, not the comments ;) Federated works also with updates. But do you mean to have always the same data on two different servers? Then you will have to have a look at (master-slave) replication. Have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html

Comment: yes i mean to have always in two different servers , sure will have a look

Answer (score 5):

AS per the MySQL documentation, When using a CONNECTION string, you cannot use an '@' character in the password. You can get round this limitation by using **"create server"** statement.

For Example:

```
CREATE SERVER fedlink
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
OPTIONS (USER 'USERNAME', HOST 'Host_IP', DATABASE 'DB_NAME', 
PORT '3306',Password 'PASSWORD');
```

Once Server Link is created, To create table that uses this connection:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (id),
INDEX name (name),
INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='fedlink/test_table';
```

Follow the links below for more information on this:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-usagenotes.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-create.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly. But can we view the created server? I mean the content of fedlink. Just like show create table, do we have something similar?

Comment: Try - `SELECT * FROM mysql.servers;`

Comment: Great! The port should be an integer, tough.