# Federated engine copy DB or points to a table in another DB connection

Tags: mysql, federated

I confused by posts ,

> that Federated engine copies a table from Remote database to local
>   database

(or)

> Federated engine creates virtual table in local database from remote
>   database

.

can some one support what it actually does.?

Comment: in Further debugging  , i came to know this, from http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/ ,  The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables. So this will not work to copy data from remote server ,can some one guide me to know what needs to be done, to copy a table from server1 to server2 .

Comment: Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297963/1432-cant-create-federated-table-the-data-source-connection-string-s-is-not/17298973?noredirect=1#comment25110008_17298973

Answer (score 0):

Federated engine creates virtual table in local database from remote database ,
To copy entire table from remote database use replication , follow http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html