# creating Federated mysql table with username password and host

Tags: mysql

My db password is Dhanu@1 contains @,

While creating FEDERATED table, I'm getting error like

> can't create federeted table. The data source connection string `mysql://dhanu:Dhanu@1@localhost:3306/mydb/items` is not in the correct format

Please help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usage of character as like these `@` is not suggested in passwords and a similar discussion on this issue is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297963/1432-cant-create-federated-table-the-data-source-connection-string-s-is-not).

You can work-around the above limitation by using `CREATE SERVER` statement as shown in the example below:

```
CREATE SERVER federatedTablelink
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
OPTIONS (USER 'USERNAME', HOST 'Host_IP', DATABASE 'DB_NAME', 
PORT '3306',Password 'PASSWORD');
```

Once the server Link is created using the step above, you can use the following to create table that uses this connection:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY  (id),
INDEX name (name),
INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='federatedTablelink/test';
```

MySQL documentation that refers to similar topics are as follows:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-usagenotes.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-create.html

Comment: How to check whether that server created or not ? i mean to ask the sql query to see that created server..

Comment: @dhanu, Have you gone through the documentation? The documentation says `The CREATE SERVER statement creates a new row in the servers table in the mysql database`